# Query OrderBy Dates stored in string Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, sql-order-by

I'm begginer in asp.net and have one problem with a list of messages which I would like to order by date. I tried some different ways, but I cannot find a way to return a result of a query ordered by date when I have those dates stored in strings in the database.

I tried something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> GetList<TResult>(IPager pager, string date = null , long? companyId = null, string content = null)
    {

        using (var context = Context.Read())
        {
            var query = context.Query<Message>().AsQueryable();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
            {
                query = query.Where(p => p.Content.Contains(content));
            }

            return query
                .OrderByDescending(d => DateTime.Parse(d.Date)).Take(10)
                .Pager(pager)
                .GetResult<TResult>();
        }
```

And I get an error. Any suggestions?

Comment: `when i have those dates stored in strings in db` : `Any suggestions?` => do not store Dates as strings ;-) .. if you do store them as string: store them as ISO sortable: YYYYMMDD.

Comment: When i was using datetime i had a conflict with format of dates in c# and sql

Comment: Then fix that conflict. SQL Date and C# DateTime go (pretty) well together.

Answer (score 0):

Using this configuration in the `DbContext` class should fix the `DateTime` conflict you mention:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Converts to datetime2 to avoid problems with Server dates and .NET dates conflicts
    modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
}
```

to allow you to store dates as `DateTime` not `string`, which will allow proper sorting using linq.